# API values inside objects return differently between Postman and application

Tags: json, reactjs, api, rest, postman

Whenever I make a call to the YGOPRO API, the values for the card_sets.set_price attribute return differently between Postman and what I get when using my React app. In Postman, the set_price values return as normal, [image: set_price returns with proper values in Postman]

But when I make the same call in my React app, the values return at "0.00"[image: set_price now returns with a different price]
This only seems to happen with a few of the objects called, and the prices render normally for almost all the rest. That leads me to believe that there is something different between how Postman calls APIs than how I do it. Has anyone else dealt with this problem?

Edit: Before you ask, yes I know that the API call for Postman is different for what is called in the app. I simply called "Toon Bookmark" by it's name to show an example in the differences in the API calls between my app and Postman. In the end, the app is suppose to identify cards based on their start and end prices, and has nothing to do with searching cards by name.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your API via Postman and React and it worked quite well. Actually such cases never happened to me. I think you should search middlewares, if your problem still remains.

Comment: I've been using axios.get() with my endpoint to make the API calls in the app. Do you think that might have something to do with it?

Comment: I tried your API using axios.get and it worked well. Have you used middleware in front-end?

Comment: Nothing that I'm aware of altering the API calls in this very particular way.
If it helps, I have the link to the git here:
https://github.com/patrickfinnigan/custom_yugioh_banlists_react
The file organization is a bit of a mess right now so fair warning. The API call in particular is in ```ygo_banlists\src\components\TestComponents\ForbiddenTestPage.js```

Comment: I've found the error. You are sending startprice and endprice, too. If you test your api with name, startprice and endprice you will get the same result with Postman,too. Seems like you have error in your backend.

Comment: I only used the Toon Bookmark search in the example as a means to show the difference between API calls, and the code in the app is suppose to search for cards based on price values and not names. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: You can check the URL in the inspect panel. I am sure it must include price query parameters.